# Mockito not returning the right type when calling Java from Scala Test

Tags: scala, mockito

I have the following code...

```
   val list : List[MyClass] = List(new MyClass)
    // Doesn't work
    doReturn(list).when(localLib).getThing(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt())
    // Doesn't work
    doReturn(list.asInstanceOf[List[MyClass]]).when(localLib).getExposedDataByDataFileId(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt())
```

When I run the test I see...

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
$colon$colon cannot be returned by getThing()
getThing() should return List
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Notice the `$colon$colon` is this a scala limitation

**MyClass is a Java class but the test is in Scala**

Comment: `import scala.collections.JavaConversions._`

Comment: Actually I couldn't get that that to work but declaring list explicitly as `java.util.Arraylist` I am willing to accept and answer from you if it works using those classes